# how to use email-js for emailing in react

Tags: reactjs

I am working on `react` project using `Emailjs` where I have a contact us form and the end-users will send emails directly to my email account, but I am not receiving emails while testing idk the reason.

NB: I tried to check if the `email-js` server is down or something but later I realized that it's working after emailjs sent me message stating 'This test email was sent to you from the EmailJS dashboard.
Tested service is **********'plus i can see emails in the emailjs dashboard

**here is my sendEmail handler:-**

```
 const sendEmail = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
 
    emailjs
      .sendForm(
        "serviceId",
        "templateId",
        formRef.current,
        "UserId"
      )
      .then(
        (result) => {
          console.log(result);
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log(error.text);
        }
      );
  };
```

**here is my contact form : -**

```
                <Form
                name="contact-form"
                id="contact-form"
                ref={formRef}
                onSubmit={sendEmail}
              >
                <div className="row">
                  <div className="col-lg-6">
                    <div className="form-group mt-2">
                      <input
                        name="name"
                        id="name"
                        type="text"
                        className="form-control"
                        placeholder="Your name* "
                        style={{ border: "2px solid lightGray" }}
                      />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="col-lg-6">
                    <div className="form-group mt-2">
                      <input
                        name="email"
                        id="email"
                        type="email"
                        className="form-control"
                        placeholder="Your email*"
                        style={{ border: "2px solid lightGray" }}
                      />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                  <div className="col-lg-12">
                    <div className="form-group mt-2">
                      <input
                        type="text"
                        className="form-control"
                        id="subject"
                        name="subject"
                        placeholder="Your Subject.."
                        style={{ border: "2px solid lightGray" }}
                      />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                  <div className="col-lg-12">
                    <div className="form-group mt-2">
                      <textarea
                        name="message"
                        id="message"
                        rows="4"
                        className="form-control"
                        placeholder="Your message..."
                        style={{ border: "2px solid lightGray" }}
                      />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                  <div className="col-lg-12 text-right">
                    <input
                      type="submit"
                      id="submit"
                      name="send"
                      className="submitBnt btn btn-custom"
                      value="Send Message"
                    />
                    <div id="simple-msg"/>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was actually in my Gmail account which was supposed to receive messages from `email-js` server but not.

**i solved the problem by signing up new emailjs account with another gmail account**

FYI : the code above is perfectly fine